# How to use PUT request in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, put

I am new in swift and I am also trying to use Alamofire to call data from API. I am quite puzzled on how I will use the **PUT Request** to update data. I've read some solutions here in SO but I don't know how I will apply on my app. I am creating an Event App, the scenario should be, when the participant clicked the **Check In** Button, it will update the `registered_flag` to `true` meaning the participant will marked as *Registered* and the button will be changed to **Check Out**. I really don't know if my API Service is correct or not. Hope you could help me. Thank you so much.

**JSON of the Event Participant Where in the registered_flag should be updated once checkInOutButton**

```
{
    "event_name": "Q & A",
    "event_participants": [
        {
            "participant_id": "70984656-92bc-4c36-9314-2c741f068523",
            "employee_number": null,
            "last_name": "Surname",
            "first_name": "FirstName",
            "middle_name": null,
            "display_name": "Surname, FirstName ",
            "department_name": "Medical Informatics",
            "position_name": "Application Developer",
            "registered_flag": true,
            "registered_datetime": "2018-09-13T08:54:40.150",
            "registration_type": 1,
            "delete_flag": false,
            "manual_reg_flag": false,
            "out_flag": false,
            "out_datetime": null,
            "classification": 6,
            "others": "Guest"
          }
        }
```

**JSON to update for check in**

```
{
   "registered_flag": true,
   "registration_type": 1
}
```

**updateType**

```
enum UpdateParticipantType: String {

case checkIn = "Check In"
case checkOut = "Check Out"
}
```

**APIService for UpdateParticipant**

```
 func updateParticipant(updateType: UpdateParticipantType,
                       participantID: String,
                       successBlock: @escaping ([Attendee]) -> Void,
                       failureBlock: @escaping (Error) -> Void)

{

   let updateParticipantURL = URL(string: "\(REGISTER_PARTICIPANT_URL)/\(updateType)/\(participantID)")

    Alamofire.request(updateParticipantURL!, method: .put).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

        if let error = response.error
        {
            failureBlock(error)
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let jsonArray = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]] {
            for anItem in jsonArray {
                if let eventparticipants = anItem["event_participants"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                    var extractedAttendees = [Attendee]()
                    for participants in eventparticipants{
                        let success = Attendee.init(JSON: participants)
                        extractedAttendees.append(success!)
                    }
                    successBlock(extractedAttendees)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to send `JSON to update for check in` on server via put request?

Comment: @inokey yes by the default `registered_flag : false` in json and once the user clicks the check in button the  `registered_flag` will be true.

Comment: you need to pass that into your `.request` in `parameters` argument

Comment: @inokey  do you have any code references so I can understand it easily?

Comment: Added example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#http-methods) documentation:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": ["a", 1],
    "qux": [
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    ]
 ]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
```

For a given json

```
 {
    "registered_flag": true,
    "registration_type": 1
 }

let parameters: Parameters = [
     "registered_flag": true
     "registration_type": 1
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Will I just add that parameters in my codes? No changes in my `jsonArray` ?

Comment: No changes in your serialization code. It's related to getting response from server, and you sending parameters TO the server. So no changes.