# How to update JSON using same API Function .PUT request in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, put

I already gathered solution regarding my previous [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307722/how-to-use-put-request-in-alamofire) regarding **How to use PUT request in ALamofire** with this solution below.

```
func updateParticipant(updateType: UpdateParticipantType,
                       participantID: String,
                       completionHandler: @escaping ( (_ result:Any?, _ error:Error?) -> Void)) {

    let updateParticipantURL = URL(string: "\(REGISTER_PARTICIPANT_URL)/\(participantID)")

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json"
    ]

    let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "registered_flag": true,
        "registration_type": 1
       // "out_flag": true
    ]


    Alamofire.request(updateParticipantURL!, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { (response) in

        print(response)


        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Done")

            if let success = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]]{
                completionHandler(success, nil)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem now is how can I update the record if the event participant will check out using the `json` below.

```
 {     
  "out_flag": true
  }
```

using the same API Function `updateParticipant` because when I tried to insert as

```
let parameters: [String : Any] = [
        "registered_flag": true,
        "registration_type": 1
        "out_flag": true
    ]
```

The participant is automatically checked out, once registered. Which is wrong because in the actual Event, the participant should register first and check in. It check outs if the event is finished. Hope you could help me regarding this issue. I am new in swift and quite puzzled in things I encountered for the first time. Thank you so much.

Comment: what is `updateType`? You are not using it currently. But i think from that you can handle adding/removing `out_flag` parameter.

Comment: @Kamran . . `updateType` is for enum `UpdateParticipantType`, `enum UpdateParticipantType: String {
    
    case checkIn = "Check In"
    case checkOut = "Check Out"
}`. How I will I construct the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the `updateType`, you can handle the parameters as below,

First change `let` to `var` so that you can add/remove a parameter based on the `updateType`. And initialize `parameters` with the common attributes as below,

```
var parameters: [String : Any] = ["registered_flag": true, "registration_type": 1]
```

now you can add optional parameters based on the `updateType`.

```
if updateType == .checkOut {
    parameters["out_flag"] = true
}
```

Similarly if you have to send some `checkIn` related parameter you can handle that also in the same way,

```
if updateType == .checkIn {
    parameters["someCheckInParameterName"] = true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much., will I add the optional parameters inside the `updateParticipants` function?

Comment: Yes, you need to update `parameters` construction as above inside `updateParticipants`

Comment: Hi again, I think I am in the wrong track of debugging `FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(409))` appeared in my console

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help. :D